# Clementine not following Xfce Theme

Tags: themes, xfce, 18.10, ubuntu-studio, clementine

I have been using Clementine as my main music player for a while now, and it has always perfectly matched the theme of my desktop environment (be that Gnome, Cinnamon or Xfce) until I installed the latest version of Ubuntu.

I am currently running Ubuntu Studio 18.10, and for whatever reason it isn't following the system theme. I have checked in Clementine's settings through; Tools>Preferences>Appearance and I have got 'Use the system default colour set' ticked. I understand that Xfce is a GTK desktop environment and Clementine is created using Qt but this has never been an issue with other GTK environments before.

To show you what I mean here is a picture of Clementine running next to Thunar: [image]

Hopefully someone knows the answer, the lighter theme Clementine is currently using just doesn't go with the rest of my system. Thank you in advance!

Edit: I can also confirm that the same thing occurs on Xubuntu 18.10

Comment: How is Clementine installed?  Via the package repository or via snaps?  (You can tell by doing `snap list` and seeing if Clementine is listed there, if it is it's installed by snap)

Comment: @ThomasWard I installed it via 'sudo apt install clementine'. Just in case I have double checked the snap list, and Clementine isn't on there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Clementine looks fine to me, has a proper Qt theme. In my case it looked like Windows 95, so my solution might not work for you. As you had no answer I though this might be useful anyway.

```
sudo apt install qt5-style-plugins qt5ct qt4-config
```

The first might be already installed. The second, `qt5ct`, Qt5 Settings, is not for Clementine, but for other Qt applications like Qmmp (simple UI), it might prove useful.

The helpful Clementine settings are to be made with Qt4 Settings (`qt4-config` package, runs as `qtconfig`) - namely selecting GUI style GTK+.

[image]

Reboot was needed in my case for changes to be adopted.

As I don't use a background image, it looks like this:

[image]

---

Considering the OP's answer that solved the problem in Ubuntu 19.04, but that doesn't work in previous versions: the question was initially about 18.10, I have tested in 18.04, the OP's solution is in 19.04. That may involve different modes of operation and versions of the Qt settings tools. I do not find surprising that the Qt4 settings tool, not the Qt5 one, is the one that worked in my case, given that **Clementine 1.3.1 uses Qt4, namely Qt 4.8.7**. The OP solved it in 19.04 with settings made in Qt5 Configuration Tool (`qt5ct`). I think that is because `qt5ct` is a newer version in the newer 19.04 Ubuntu, while mine (version 0.34 from Ubuntu 18.04) not only behaves but also looks a bit different:

[image]

***It might be that the newer version of *Qt5 Settings*  has taken over the Qt4 options too.***

---

### Summing it up:

- **In Xubuntu 19.04 and later, use the Qt5 Settings (`qt5ct`), as said in the OP's answer.**
- **In previous versions where the above doesn't work, like in Xubuntu 18.04  and 18.10, use the Qt4 Settings (`qt4-config` package, runs as `qtconfig`).** (For other Qt applications like Qmmp with Simple UI, depending on their Qt version, the Qt5 Settings might be the one useful though. I have also seen a case where Qmmp with Simple UI would not follow the system (dark) theme unless the setting in the Qt5 tool was changed accordingly under *Palette - Custom - Color scheme*.)
- **Reboot might be needed to see changes.**

Comment: None of those packages were already installed, so I installed all three of them (I had to install the config as qt4-qtconfig). After a quick reboot Clementine is still not following the theme, however all of the text is now larger... I will mess around with the config and see if I can get it to play ball

Comment: take a look https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176696/341192

Answer (score 3):

So I have to tip my hat to @cipricus who got it almost right with the info he had. When I tried his solution on 18.10 the Qt5 Settings wouldn't load, however having tried this on Ubuntu Studio 19.04, I was able to get it to load by just installing:

```
sudo apt install qt5ct qt5-style-plugins
```

This then allowed me to run Qt5 Settings and change the style and standard dialogue to GTK2. This seems to have worked for me, however, I am concerned that it is set to GTK2 and I don't have the option to change it to GTK3.

[image]

Anyway here are the results with a much nicer (in my opinion) looking dark theme:

[image]

Comment: Your 19.04-specific answer (marked as definitive) is not the good one for your 18.10-specific question, as they stand now: they refer to different versions of Ubuntu with different tools and versions available for the needed purposes. (A reader confronted with your initial problem will **not** be able to use your definitive answer.) In order for your answer to stand as definitive, you should either edit your question and/or (even better) include a bit more complex info in your answer (see the "Summing up" part at the end of my answer)